# DatePart: How to set its language

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Has anyone been able to set a different language when using [DatePart](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/DatePart.htm)? I currently have my AMPScript producing the month name, but it's in English. I'm trying to set it up so that it will produce the month name in Spanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format will give you the day/month in local culture code

`%%=FormatDate(Now(), "MMMM",,"es-ES")=%%`

Comment: I do see the months changing, but it’s throwing an error for me. I’m going to keep poking around.
—
An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a DatePart function call. See inner exception for details.
Invalid value specified for function parameter.
Function Name: datepart
Parameter Name: Date
Parameter Ordinal: 1
Parameter Type: Date
Submitted Value: lundi 15 juin 1:45
JobID: 0
ListID: 0
BatchID: 0
SubcriberID: 0
Data Source Type: CustomObject

Comment: I've just updated my answer - give the new code a try - that should work. My first attempt was written on a phone. I also though if a way to further simplify without the DatePart piece